# How to get and write non-EXIF tags from JPGs?

Tags: python, tags, metadata, exif

I have a jpg dataset labelled through Windows' native "Tags" field. For example, "dog", "table", etc... I've then made a derivative dataset with some transforms, but the tools used did not transfer the tags over.

All search for this scenario returns only EXIF-specific or web-scraping related discussions. I have tried them (e.g. PIL, pillow, piexif), but apparently the tags I'm working with are not a subset of EXIF tags/metadata.

Does anyone know how non-EXIF tags can be read/written/manipulated, preferably in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Python code to accomplish this task:

```
from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts
xmpfile = XMPFiles(file_path='path_to_your_file.jpg', open_forupdate=True)
xmp = xmpfile.get_xmp()
print(xmp.get_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, 'prop'))
print(xmp.get_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, 'prop'))
xmp.set_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, 'prop', 'value')
xmpfile.can_put_xmp(xmp)
xmpfile.put_xmp(xmp)
xmpfile.close_file()
```

Please work with the copy of your file since it overwrites the data.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Have to agree with Jeremy here. I am grateful for your answer, but in this case the libxmp library (https://python-xmp-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) doesn't seem exhaustively documented. I'm not sure if the tags I'm referring to are related to Adobe's XMP, and I can't find mention of 'prop', 'value'. Are they placeholder strings, or something else?